# Boot Struck on Ubuntu Loading screen

Tags: boot, grub2

I use A HP laptop with Dual OS Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04

Recently, I have a problem with booting the computer freezes.

I have to reboot again to solve it and also sometimes use fsck /dev/sda6 to solve it.

Yesterday, suddenly it is staying at the Ubuntu loading screen for hours (see image).

[image]

I don't know much about the OS.

Comment: Looks like its not able to resolve a dependancy for the USB flash disk.

Comment: How to Solve that Problem ??